# Android update current activity when service stop

Tags: android, service, refresh

I want to ask a question about the best way to reload activity when my service stops. So what I'm doing is:

- I'm downloading data from JSON API via service and I'm showing a progressbar while doing this on top of all activities in my application.

What I want to do is:

- When my service stops (all the data is downloaded) I want to refresh the current activity.

So any ideas on which is the best way and what do I have to use to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) in this case. Just send your Intent to the IntentServices `onHandleIntent()` do your background process and fire a `BroadCastReceiver` to update your Activity.

[`Example for IntentService Updating UI.`](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics/)

Comment: Thanks for example and answer!

Answer (score 0):

When ever your service is being stopped, you will get a call back in your class which extends service, in that class override the

```
onDestroy();
```

Reason: When ever your service is being stopped every time you will get a callback to         onDestroy();

Here in that block you can refresh your Activity(By finishing it and starting again)